# Ajax Call replace single quote jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
function RejectItem(link, compqID, comments, officerID) {
    if ($(link).parent().find("div.divComments").is(":visible")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../contentService.asmx/RejectComplianceItem",
            data: "{ 'compqID': '" + compqID + "', 'comments': '" + $(link).parent().find("div.divComments").find('.taComments').val() + "', 'officerID': '" + officerID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                hideRow(compqID);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(link).parent().find("div.divComments").show();
    }
}
```

Whenever `($(link).parent().find("div.divComments").find('.taComments').val())` returns a value that has single quote in this function, it fails.

Any fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to encode the data you send as JSON? If so, then your JSON is not valid anyway. Strings and keys must be enclosed in double quotes.

Use [`JSON.stringify` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Converting_objects_into_JSON):

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    compqID: compqID,
    comments: $(link).parent().find("div.divComments").find('.taComments').val(), 
    officerID: officerID
}),
```

The `JSON` implementation is also available [here](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Comment: @Richard: It encodes the object as JSON. Better than building it manually and it takes care of proper escaping.

Comment: @Richard: In recent browsers, `JSON` is built-in. jQuery only provides a method to parse JSON.

Comment: @user856246: Please accept the answer then by clicking the tick outline next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the single quotes.  Something like this.

```
$(link).parent().find("div.divComments").find('.taComments').val().replace("'", "\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function RejectItem(link, compqID, comments, officerID) {
        if ($(link).parent().find("div.divComments").is(":visible")) {
            var data = { 'compqID': compqID, 'officerID': officerID, 
                  'comments': $(link).parent().find("div.divComments").find('.taComments').val()};

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../contentService.asmx/RejectComplianceItem",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    hideRow(compqID);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(link).parent().find("div.divComments").show();
        }        


    }
```